# NativeScript Button Tap event doesn't call ngOnInit after navigation but onTap does

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I'm currently writing a TypeScript app where the buttons are programatically created and added to a GridLayout.

```
    let currentPage;
    let topFrame = frameModule.topmost();
    currentPage = topFrame.currentPage;

    currentPage.actionBarHidden = true;
    currentPage.backgroundImage = currentPage.ios ? "res://baby_large_file.jpg" : "res://baby_large_file";

    var onTap = function (eventData) {
        this.login();
    };

    var grid = new GridLayout();
    let feeding = new buttonModule.Button();
    feeding.text = "F";
    feeding.id = "feeding";
    feeding.on(buttonModule.Button.tapEvent, onTap, this);

    grid.addChild(feeding);

    grid.addRow(new ItemSpec(1, GridUnitType.star));
    grid.addColumn(new ItemSpec(1, GridUnitType.star));

    GridLayout.setRow(feeding, 0);// shareButton set to row 2
    GridLayout.setColumn(feeding, 0);// shareButton set to row 2

    currentPage.content = grid;
```

The login function simply calls a user service and if the app has a valid token they are routed to a new page:

```
    login() {
    this.userService.login(this.user)
        .subscribe(
        () => this.router.navigate(["/locations"]),
        (error) => alert("Unfortunately we could not find your account.")
    );

}
```

The ngOnInit function is never called in this new page

```
export class Locations implements OnInit {
    constructor (private router: Router, private locationService: LocationService ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('ngOnInit');
    }
}
```

Any help with why this doesn't work would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Being in an Angular-2 environment it is a better workflow to navigate with NG techniques instead with a mix of NativeScript and Angular-2.
That said I would recommend navigating using the NG2 way for example with **nsRouterLink** and avoid using Button for navigation (can use Label instead like [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/master/app/examples-list.component.html))
If you are worried about how to control the services then you can implement [route guards](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html) for cases like signin/login forms.

That said, the same is pretty much valid for the creation of your components. Instead, with the NativeScript code technique, you can create your template using Angular directives and reuse them whenever you want in your application.
Examples [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/directives) and [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/ui-category/ng-directives/create-custom-directive)